# An End to Endings

Tags: discussion, tags, burnination

[endings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/endings)

Is it a useful tag? It strikes me as a prime candidate for burnination. It's attached to 54 questions, so an edit spree seems like a bad idea here.

Do we need this tag?

Comment: What about spoilers? Ignoring story and endings could presumably help me ignore questions *focused* around spoilers at least.

Comment: Tags that exist solely so you can ignore them to avoid content you don't want are functionally meta tags. They are bad and evil and wrong and should be burninated.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I haven't seen any action taken on this. Is there not enough consensus to move forward? I ask because I recently [asked a question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/59324/3062) for which [tag:endings] would be appropriate, if it's going to stay around.

Comment: @Sterno 1) The problem is twofold: 1) There are too many questions tagged as such for me to feel comfortable spamming the homepage on a crusade to be rid of it, and 2) the merge/synonym proposal put forward by Raven Dreamer is fundamentally unworkable given the diversity of kinds of questions currently under the tags heading. Hence, my request that it be burninated, rather than simply cleared out by someone editing.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I'll take that to mean we shouldn't be adding it to new questions, then. My question shall remain unsullied with it!

Answer (score 7):

**I'm of the mind that both [story](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story) and [endings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/endings) should both be squashed.**

I can't imagine a scenario of anyone following either tag in an effort to find questions that they can answer, nor do I think either tag is useful from a perspective of "I want to ignore questions of this type".

If people are not wanting to hear about endings, they probably don't want to hear about [spoilers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoilers) in general. If they're having issues "beating the end guy", then I think they've mis-labled a question entirely.

[story](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story) items aren't something I can conceive of many people ignoring as well. In addition, I don't think [story](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story) is needed as a way to quickly identify the type of question being asked. That's pretty self-evident from the title of those kinds of questions.

Comment: Sidenote: We got rid of [tag:spoilers]? I'd think there'd be a sizable group who ignored that tag on purpose, but maybe actual usage proved otherwise?

Comment: [tag:Spoilers] is a meta tag and an awful tag and deserved extra discriminatory squashing.

Answer (score 4):

I think the "I have a question about this game's ending" type [endings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/endings) questions falls squarely into the broader category of [story](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story), and there's not enough granularity to warrant the former, given the existence of the latter.

Questions which use [endings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/endings) as a part of the game are using it as a meta tag, and deserve to be simply removed. (Same reason we wouldn't have a [beginnings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginnings))

Unless anyone has a better idea, I have no problem merging them, and removing the remainder.

Comment: A fair number of the questions currently tagged [tag:endings] are actually primarily mechanical questions about the games finale, or about branching paths that get there. While a fair number of questions with this tag can (and should) be tagged with [tag:story] if we're going to keep *that* tag around, I'm not sure about a merge.

Answer (score 1):

The only semi-valid use of the [endings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/endings) tag that I can imagine would be if someone mistakenly used it as a synonym for "late-game", such as:

*Only 40 seconds left in the game, but Tibbers is guarding the Nexus...should I push?*

**I vote for remove.**