# Export of tags with disproportionate question-to-follower ratio?

Tags: support, tags

We've had a few discussions lately about proper use of tags on SGE:

- [Let's talk about Mods [baby]](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3723/lets-talk-about-mods/3725)
- [An End to Endings](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3738/an-end-to-endings)
- [Request for Tag Burnination: Review](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3423/request-for-tag-burnination-review)

All are based off of the same concepts:

- [Meta Tags are Bad](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)
- [SEO is Good](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2266/allow-tags-to-be-blacklisted-specifically-from-appearing-in-the-html-page-title/3704#3704)

I would like to clean up (delete/merge/rename) tags and bring more order to the chaos. What would be helpful to me is a view where I can see tags that have been used on many questions but aren't followed by many people. Adding this as another view on the tabs view would be convenient.

The threshold is debatable, of course, and should be based on the average number of followers on a tag.

In addition, I'd like to see a reverse view of the 'popular' tag listing. In other words, a view where I see the least-used tags that aren't synonyms for established tags.

I realize that the idea solution is to solve the problem of how people tag, and I do think we should have mechanisms in place to educate new users (maybe a listing of rules near the tags field). However, I think regular maintenance is going to prove necessary to keep tags in a healthy state, and this would help with such maintenance.

Comment: Don't the tag wikis and their excerpts serve as a "listing of rules"? Most of the non-game title tags we have have descriptions/instructions as to how they should be used.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes They do, but my guess is that they are largely ignored since they are behind a mouseover tooltip.

Comment: You might also be interested in my related feature-request on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81395/sort-tags-by-number-of-followers-add-a-tab-to-the-tag-page

Comment: Seems like it should be enough to simply review the first two pages to tags to view the actual problem tags. If they're not very common it's not a very big deal, and it's less likely you'd be able to pick up on any sort of patterns due to higher variability.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is in my "api tool" queue, in the event that this isn't a feature that the SE devs are interested in doing (or have done already and I'm too dense to have noticed it to date).  I'm in the middle of one project now, but I estimate I'll have time to think about this in the next couple of weeks.

In the meantime, this list is frequently illuminating:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new

And there's always the data explorer if you're handy with SQL and don't mind things being a bit stale:

http://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. I know about new tags and have started checking it out, but it has proven insufficient for my level of zealotry. :)

Comment: Unless I missed it in a quick glance, data.se doesn't seem to show the followers of a tag.

Comment: @CruelCow, your quick glance is probably better than mine, which was some time ago.  I haven't dug into it, just suggesting it as a source of candidates.

Comment: @CruelCow, that is correct. Follower count is not one of the tag properties to which we have access at this time.

Comment: Yeah, it's not part of the API either.  I've asked for this to be added, but I think the request has been deferred to the next release.